# Azure Data flow - presql script, dynamic content

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I want to run a presql script in the Data flow in SINK. I want to delete exiting records for particular year.
This particular year will be coming from source excel file.

Say I have a file for 2021 data and loaded that data into DB. when I rerun the pipeline for the same excel file I want to delete 2021 related records in DB and insert fresh. This table may contain multiple years data. So everytime a new file arrives for a particular year, I want to delete that respective records and reload the new data.

I can read the year value from source file column. And I can keep it as derived column. How Can I write a presql script to delete?

delete from  where year = <sourcefile.year>

how can i do this in data flow?
Pls help!

Comment: Would it be better to use an Alter Row delete policy and turn on Deletes in the database sink instead of using a SQL script in the Sink?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **temporary table** in sink1 and delete the records in the sink2.

Please follow the demonstration below:

This is my SQL table with a sample data.

[image]

Create two SQL sinks for it from same source using a **new branch**.

In the first sink, provide a dataset with edit table name option for the temporary table.

[image]

In sink check on Recreate table.

[image]

In sink 2, give your SQL table with the below SQL script.

```
DELETE FROM  exceltable WHERE year in (select year from dbo.temp1)
drop table dbo.temp1;
```

[image]

In the settings of Data flow give the Write order of sinks.

[image]

Temporary table sink should execute first.

This is my result in the SQL table after deleting records.

[image]