# ADF Azure Data Factory - dataflow delete row

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

A table in Azure SQL holds information About Order Lines. For each order there can be multiple lines, with no primary key for the table
Img here:

[image]

Upsert and insert work fine by using a sha1 generated column based on order_id + product_sku + product_qantity. Hence each time the quantity changes for a given line, the quantity is changed on the sink.

[image]

for the exists step i use a match between source and sink, source being the order_lines table in azure sql. The following conditions
flatten2@products_sku == source2@products_sku && checksum@sha1 == source2@sha1

[image]

The Alter row looks like this

[image]

Upsert and insert work fine
However, i cannot make the delete work, for scenarios when a product is being removed from an order line.

Any suggestion on how this can be achieved?

thanks

Comment: tried moving the delete rule in the alter row transformation as the first one in the list, no success

Comment: Can you please provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this and not able to delete the records in the target using alter row.

As an alternative, you can try the below approach to delete the records in database target.

This is my sample **source table**:

[image]

Sample **targe table**:

[image]

To delete the records, you can use script in sink.

For sample, here I want to delete the record with name `'Rakesh'`in sink and insert the source as it is.
I have used the below script in sink Post SQL script.

```
delete from source1 where name='Rakesh'
```

[image]

You can use pre script or post script as per your requirement and change the query according to your condition.

**Target table with source data and without `'Rakesh'` row after Execution:**

[image]

Comment: hello @Rakesh and thank you very much for your detailed response!

The question i have regarding this approach is related to the fact that the rows that are going to be changed are dinamic hence i cannot use a statement similar to "where name = 'Rakesh' ". It needs to be dynamic since order lines may change (eg: sku's/ products being removed from an order).

Any other idea? Surely there is a solution

Comment: yeah, I tried with alter row and able to delete the records only if the source and sink are same. If source and sink are different, then the records in sink are not deleted. So as per my repro, alter row can't delete data already present in sink table, only data that is going to be placed in the sink table will be deleted.

Comment: in my case, both source and sink are the same. Source 2 in the pictures above is equal to the sink

Comment: yeah, but you are adding another source1. I think that's why it is not deleting the records.

Comment: If you want, you can use a combination of pre-sql scripts and alter row delete to achieve your requirement.

Comment: any suggestion how to do that, meaning how to leverage the sku name in the sink that does not exist anymore in the source1? In source one i am looking at a REST API which takes order lines from the orders on our website. So when a line is removed from an order, we want this to be reflected in the azure sql sink.

Comment: I think you can try a temporary table for source in sink database like this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73209750/azure-data-flow-presql-script-dynamic-content/73583213#73583213